# Java EE can't complete SessionContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, sessioncontext

To rollback when have error, I use **javax.ejb.SessionContext** to do that,

first I mark a point to rollback by `sessionContext.getUserTransaction().begin()`

Then I use `sessionContext.getUserTransaction().rollback()` to rollback and use `sessionContext.getUserTransaction().commit();` to `should complete transaction before returning.`

but the problem is if there is nothing changed, this will throws `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement`.
Conclusion: There is anyway to stop SessionContext ?

Comment: Are you really using EJBs? Because, the whole point of using EJBs is that you never need to manually deal with user transactions. So far it looks like your application is seriously wrongly configured, or that you don't understand how to use EJBs correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I also confuse about "is it the right way to deal with rollback?" Thanks ^_^.